# How to get the selected argonTab in a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

Can someone show me how to get the `tabName` of the selected `argonTab` in an `argonTabSet` please, in a shiny app. I need it for downstream data subsetting.

The example below follows, somewhat, my actual app, where I call `argonTabSet` with `do.call`. The tabnames in my real app can vary so I am looking for something without hard coding them. The app is modularised, though I can’t get any values to return with `input$t_brnd` if I also wrap the `argonTabSet` id in `ns()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(argonR)
library(argonDash)


mod_price_ov_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns('ot_cat_brnd_rtlr'))
    , uiOutput(ns('selected_tab'))
    )
}

mod_price_ov <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) {
      output$ot_cat_brnd_rtlr <- renderUI({
        
        ns <- session$ns
        
        brands <- paste0('brand_', 1:4)
        tagList(
          do.call(argonTabSet, c(
            # id = ns('t_brnd'), 
            id ='t_brnd', 
            lapply(1:length(brands), function(i) {
            argonTab(
              tabName = brands[i],
              active  = ifelse(i == 1, T, F)
            )
          })
          ))
        )
      })
      
      output$selected_tab <- renderUI({
        
        input$t_brnd
        
      })
    })
}

shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = argonDashPage(
    body = argonDashBody(mod_price_ov_UI('ov'))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    mod_price_ov('ov')
  }
)
```

UPDATE
A comment (which seems to have been deleted) asked for an example closer to the actual use case, which I present below. I may need to revise the question title as the example now illustrates my actual issue. I thought that getting the tabname would ultimately help me get to this point.

The table `category_tally` starts with an overall summary total. I require to provide some functionality (with a radiobutton ‘Brand Stats ’ for example) where the user can update the total filtered by the brand in the selected tabname (also reflected in the selected datatable) , and back again, if the button equals ‘NO’.

I can only seem to get the button to work on the last tab, not the first 3.

```
library(shiny)
library(argonR)
library(argonDash)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

set.seed(1234)

mod_price_ov_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tableOutput(ns('category_tally')),
    uiOutput(ns('ot_cat_brnd_rtlr')))
}

mod_price_ov <- function(id){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      toy_rtcv <- reactive({tibble(
          category   = sample(paste0('cat_'  , 1:3), 100, replace = T)
          , brand    = sample(paste0('brand_', 1:4), 100, replace = T)
        )})
      
      output$category_tally <- renderTable({toy_rtcv() %>% summarise(total = n())})
      
      output$ot_cat_brnd_rtlr <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        brands <- toy_rtcv() %>% select(brand) %>% distinct() %>% pull(brand)
        tagList(
          do.call(argonTabSet, c(id= 't_brnd', lapply(1:length(brands), function(i) {
            argonTab(
              tabName  = brands[i]
              , active = ifelse(i == 1, T, F)
              , radioButtons(ns(paste0('rdio_cat_brnd_rtlr', brands[i]))
                             , 'Brand Stats'
                             , choices = c('YES', 'NO')
                             , selected = 'NO'
                             , inline = T
              )
              , dataTableOutput(ns(paste0('ot_retailer_', brands[i])))
            )}))))})
      
      observe({
        brands <- toy_rtcv() %>% select(brand) %>% distinct() %>% pull(brand)
        lapply(1:length(brands), function(i) {
          output[[paste0('ot_retailer_', brands[i])]]  = renderDataTable({
            toy_rtcv() %>% 
              filter(brand == brands[i])
          })})})
      
      observe({
        brands <- toy_rtcv() %>% select(brand) %>% distinct() %>% pull(brand)
        lapply(1:length(brands), function(i){

          if(is.null(input[[paste0('rdio_cat_brnd_rtlr', brands[i])]]))
            return(NULL)
          
          if(input[[paste0('rdio_cat_brnd_rtlr', brands[i])]] == 'YES'){
            output$category_tally <- renderTable({
              toy_rtcv() %>%
                filter(brand == brands[i]) %>%
                summarise(total = n())})
          } else {
            output$category_tally <- renderTable({
              toy_rtcv() %>%
                summarise(total = n())
            })}})})})
}


shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = argonDashPage(
    body = argonDashBody(mod_price_ov_UI('ov'))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {mod_price_ov('ov')}
)
```

Comment: The actual case is much more complicated. I am looking to subset data based on the brand in the tabname, and from that update/replace the values in other ui elements. brands <- paste0('brand_', 1:4) is actually a column (unique values) in a larger dataset.

Comment: Can you use `brands <- unique(yourdata$yourcol)`

Comment: @akrun - I have updated with an example much closer to the use case. Thnx